# Understanding Lattice based cryptosystem

Tags: lattice-crypto

I have heard that there is one paradigm of Public key cryptosystem, called **Lattice based crytography**. Further, its security claims are such that it will not be affected even if the quantum computers are available.

Would any one be kind enough to help me to understand the basic philosophy behind it, with examples?

**EDIT**
As stated in comments, I don't any complete, state-of-the-art scenario of this system. I am only interested to know what are the basic pillars that constitute it. I mean, there has to be something like complicated non-linear operations, or finding prime factor(s) of a large number etc.

Comment: I’m not really sure I get what you’re asking. You’re not asking us to explain lattice-based crypto from scratch, are you? That would be a bit too broad. But editing your question will probably help narrowing it down a bit… *What research have you done, and what exactly are you having a hard time with or don’t you understand?*

Comment: @e-sushi I don't want it from the scratch. I only want to know the idea behind it. I mean, public key cryptosystems are based on factorization, finding discrete log; private key cryptosystems are based on some random-looking permutations or complicated non-linear functions etc. Now, what makes lattice based system strong?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: It seems that the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice-based_cryptography), or/and for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GGH_encryption_scheme) or [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUSign) example it cites, is enough to answer _what makes lattice based system strong?_ with: for many, the hardness of the [Closest Vector Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_vector_problem) in some appropriate lattice. Perhaps, state this and ask for more, e.g. what the CVP is, or why it is believed to be secure even with quantum computers?